# How to set up a git repo with existing sources

Tags: git

I am new to git and I have difficulty understanding some functioning.

I have 1 production server, 1 staging server and 1 development machine.

Of these 3 machines, I have the sources of the application. I would like to connect each machine to the repo git I created and more precisely, I would like to create 3 branches (master, staging, prod) and connect the production server to the prod branch, staging server to staging branch and development machine to the master branch.

I can not create this system and import the sources into the branches ... I'm lost with git commands...

Please, how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `git init` to initialize a git repo.
2. the repo is empty. So easily create branches for `production` and `staging`:

   ```
   git branch production
   git branch staging
   ```
3. the default branch is called `master`. So, add your `development` code into it.
4. add the code to git index and commit.

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "init development source code"
   ```
5. Checkout the `production` branch and repeat steps 3 and 4.

   ```
    git checkout production
    [...]
    git add .
    git commit -m "..."
   ```
6. Repeat for staging

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have to change a little your commands but it works. (git remote add origin & git push -u origin master & git push -u origin staging)